# Facebook - refer a friend

Tags: facebook

I'd like to enquire with the Facebook heads on here about how best to do the following:

I'd like to run a promotion from my Facebook business page that encourages users to recommend a friend in order to gain access to enter a competition. Obviously being in the Facebook environment it would be preferred to encourage Facebookers to refer friend's on their profile. Anybody know if there's an app out there (I've searched and not found) that does this? Does the Facebook API allow access to select specific friend(s) to notify on Facebook?

Thanks for your help & suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to have `read_friendlists` as an added permission to your facebook app.

From there I think you can do a `FB.api()` kind of call to get that information

[Source](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: I know I saw an app that does this. Let me try to find it

Comment: Thanks very useful. If you could find that app that's be spectacular! Cheers.

Comment: @PepperedLemons I think that app no longer exists? (its just going to a FB page)

Comment: @Zach, That could be true. I hear that Facebook did some major graph updates recently which would make this answer useless, but I no longer work with the API so I cannot confirm this.

Comment: no; I mean the link in the comments: http://www.facebook.com/sisterwives?sk=app_115105668563689 no longer contains an app

Comment: Oh... The company took that down a while ago. Let me remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) does what you were looking for?